# Does the MULTI/EXEC command in phpredis send the command at once?

Tags: redis, exec

PhpRedis, the Redis client driver for PHP, transmits multiple commands inside MULTI/EXEC to Redis server at multiple times or just one time?

Thanks

PhpRedis : https://github.com/nicolasff/phpredis

Answer (score 0):

According to the source code, PhpRedis apparently sends MULTI/EXEC blocks as several commands (involving several network packets). Pipelines, however, are sent as a single block of commands.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5280553/does-each-call-within-a-multi-call-in-phpredis-result-in-a-new-network-roundtr